# How to post a project with Gitlab API that sets also a default_branch

Tags: angularjs, gitlab

I try to create a project in gitlab via their API,
with a request (in angular) like this :

```
$http.post(
   "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects",
   {private_token: <token>}
)
```

But then I get, as a returned data, a project document with a default_branch : null  ... and then it is impossible to update the project by for example post files with the API "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects//repository/files" because gitlab will return me an error that I need to be in a specified branch.

Unfortunately a post of a branch with

```
$http.post(
"https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/<projectId>/repository/branches",
 {
   private_token: <token>
   branch_name: "master"
 } 
)
```

returns me also an error... because I need to specify also a ref parameter, but it would make any sense if I don't have yet an origin master branch !

Answer (score 0):

If your project is **empty** (contains no git objects), you should be able to post to "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/repository/files", and specify a branch name, and that will become your default branch. If that isn't working, open a bug on: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues